# Log file ./ib_logfile0 size 50331649 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size

Tags: mysql

When I restart mysql service! It started failed!

The error message as follow(/var/log/mysql/error.log):

[The error messgae picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwa78.png)

```
2017-07-01T09:14:17.198799Z 0 [Warning] option 'server_id_bits': unsigned value 33 adjusted to 32
2017-07-01T09:14:17.198977Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-07-01T09:14:17.201679Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17-log) starting as process 1880 ...
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207120Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207185Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207195Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207204Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207212Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207226Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207685Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-07-01T09:14:17.207870Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-07-01T09:14:17.210105Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-07-01T09:14:17.224792Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-07-01T09:14:17.228042Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-07-01T09:14:17.240603Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 size 50331649 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2017-07-01T09:14:17.240644Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-07-01T09:14:17.841070Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-07-01T09:14:17.841115Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-07-01T09:14:17.841130Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-07-01T09:14:17.841140Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: I just notice the error as follow:

[ERROR] InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 size 50331649 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size.

so,I directly delete the file：
/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 、/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1.

Then I restart mysql. It work! But i do not know why?

Comment: Did you have an unexpected system shutdown or did you run out of disk space? Are there any earlier mysql log entries?  This isn't something that should be possible on a stable server, and it's a fatal error since an unaligned log file is corrupt by definition.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  Thanks! The reason may be that I forced shutdown the system.